# convolution the standard normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Quote: If you convolution the standard normal distribution with "{+ 1, -1} = 50/50%" then again there will be a standard normal distribution.

Answer: The standard normal distribution is a centered normal (Gaussian) distribution with a normalized variance. Convolution corresponds to the distribution of the sum of independent random variables. Dispersions of a random variable add up when added, so, given that the variance of the {-1.1} -distribution is not zero (equal to 1), the convolution variance will be more than one (equal to 2), that is, convolution will no longer be the standard normal distribution. Correctly?

Comment: Two beers and a shot... I'm not that drunk. What is the question?

Comment: maybe difficulties with translation!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your answer is correct, the statement you quote is false.

Some additional comments:

- The verb corresponding to the noun “convolution” is “convolve”.
- “Dispersions of a random variable add up when added” – here you implicitly used the independence.
- The resulting distribution is not only not a standard normal distribution, but not even a normal distribution. It's the sum of two Gaussians, which can't be written as a single Gaussian.

Comment: "Yes, that's correct." is slightly odd in view of the (correct) "additional comments" that come after, since the last of these (correctly) contradicts the belief that the sum is normal which the question seems to (incorrectly) endorse.

Comment: @Did: The question seemed heavily in need of interpretation. I interpreted it to mean that the OP saw this quote, wanted to check it and disproved in the part labeled "Answer". I've clarified my answer :-).